# grant a role to a selected subset

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a role I want to grant to a selected subset of users. Can someone help me with the syntax? Something like this:

```
grant my_special_role to (select username from dba_users where username like 'john%')
```

This is supposed to grant `my_special_role` to all users named John!

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in a loop, declarating a block of code

```
declare
begin
for rec in (select username from dba_users where username like 'john%')
loop
 execute immediate 'grant my special role to ' || rec.username;
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like the right ting to do!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple PL/SQL loop to execute the grants to all the users

```sql
BEGIN
    FOR i IN (SELECT username
                FROM dba_users
               WHERE username LIKE 'john%')
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'grant my_special_role to ' || i.username;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like the right ting to do!